# Django forms ChoiceField causing form validation to fail

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
desig = []
class New_user_form(UserCreationForm):
    desig = forms.ChoiceField(choices=desig)
    def acquire_groups(self):
        g = Group.objects.all()
        for k in g:
             desig.append((k.name, k.name))
        print(desig)

    def save(self, commit=True):
         user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
         designation = self.cleaned_data["desig"]
         print("New_user_form save : Designation :", designation)
         if commit:
              user.save()
              g = Groups.objects.filter(name=designation)
              print("acquired group", g[0].name)
              user.groups.add(g)
         return user
```

The following is my view:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = New_user_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form Validated")
            new_user = form.save()
            HttpResponse("Success")
        else:
            HttpResponse("Invalid Form")
    else:
        form = New_user_form()
        form.acquire_groups()
        g = Group.objects.all()
        desig = []
        for k in g:
            desig.append(k.name)
        args = {}
        args.update({'user':request.user.username,
                     'form':form,
                     'STATIC_URL':settings.STATIC_URL,
                     'desig': desig,})
        return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

[image: html template]

I have tried to save the form many times and it always does not validate. I dont understand why the choice field fails. I am able to use the form without the choice field. But I want to use the choice field to add new users to an existing group.
I dont understand why the form is getting invalid.

EDIT: I have changed my form as follows:

```
class New_user_form(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    desig = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        u = UserCreationForm.__init__(self, kwargs)
        try:
            if kwargs['desig_group']:
                print("desig_group instantiated. Found kwargs = ", kwargs['desig_group'])
            else:
                print("desig_group not instantiated")
         except (AttributeError, KeyError) as ex:
            for g in Group.objects.all():
                self.desig.append((g.name, g.name))
                print("desig : ", self.desig)
                desig_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

          def save(self, commit=True):
              user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
              user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
              user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
              designation = self.cleaned_data["desig_group"]
              print("New_user_form save : Designation :", designation)
              if commit:
                  user.save()
                  g = Groups.objects.filter(name=designation)
                  print("acquired group", g[0].name)
                  user.groups.add(g)
              return user
```

I have changed my view now as :

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("request.POST = ", request.POST)
        form = New_user_form(**request.POST)
        print("form bound: ", form.is_bound)
        print("Form bool: ", bool(form.errors))
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form Validated")
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Added new user")
        else:
            print("Form is invalid")
            HttpResponse("Invalid form submission.")
    else:
        form = New_user_form()
        g = Group.objects.all()
        desig = []
        for k in g:
            desig.append(k.name)
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args.update({'user':request.user.username,
                     'form':form,
                     'STATIC_URL':settings.STATIC_URL,
                     'desig': desig,})
        return render_to_response('emp_users/register.html', args)
```

With this, my form is not passing validation but all the required data is arriving in POST.
I just need to know how to validate it now.

```
form.cleaned_data['desig_group']
```

returns KeyError but the POST has that value in its query dictionary

The following is my POST:

[image: request.POST dump]

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the choices after the form is initialized. Instead, just set the choices as such:

```
# forms.py
class New_user_form(UserCreationForm):
    desig = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())
    ...


# views.py
def register_user(request):
    form = New_user_form(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form Validated")
            new_user = form.save()

    args = {}
    args.update({'user':request.user.username,
        'form':form, 'STATIC_URL':settings.STATIC_URL,
        'desig': desig,})
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Comment: That didn't work. I have my form in forms.py and views in views.py. I have changed the form to the way you mentioned but kept the view code same as before.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put in comments separating the code into their respective files, but that's what I intended.

Comment: It still dint solve my problem yet. I need to make sure I get it through validation.

Comment: Form validation is failing. no errors really. form.is_valid() is false.

Comment: which part is invalid?

Comment: The form as a whole is returning invalid. I have updated a few changes. Have you seen my edit ?

Comment: Like I said. No error. form.is_valid returns false.

Comment: If `form.is_valid()` is returning `False`, there's an error somewhere. It may not be a field related error. Have you checked `form.non_field_errors()` ?

Comment: No. It gives an error Model form has no attribute form.non_field_errors().
It starts to work after the django server prints
"Validating models..." once in a while.

Comment: Sorry. There was some typing mistakes.
form.non_field_errors() returns nill. empty.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how much I'm going to be able to help on this one.

Comment: In any case, Thanks for all the time and effort. :-)